# WPF is it possible to showdialog() on top of Windows lock screen?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I wrote a desktop alerts application that sends a variety of notifications to all clients that are currently logged in.  The app lives in the system tray, with a right-click menu to select an alert.  When an alert is sent, a pop-up displays on each client's desktop with the type of alert.  The pop-up is a simple Window class:

```
alertWindow.showDialog();
```

Our PC's have a policy on them to automatically lock the screen after 10 minutes of inactivity.  What I'd like to know is if there's any way to have the alerts display while the screen is locked.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could put the required information into an image and then change the lock screen background with the [Windows.System.UserProfile.Lockscreen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.userprofile.lockscreen.aspx) class in the Windows Runtime APIs.

```
Windows.System.UserProfile.LockScreen.SetImageFileAsync(file);
```

Comment: Is this not available for Windows 7?  This only seems to be usable for Windows 8/10.

Answer (score 1):

The lock-screen itself is de-facto a different user session which runs with `winlogon` privileges.

I've done such thing under window 7 quite a while ago, but cant recall the details right now.

The general approach is:

- open `winlogon` process handle
- copy access token from process
- create a new process with the just copied access token
- create your windows on the lock-screen

It's a pretty hacky approach using many API calls, but the only one that works.

### Edit:

I now had the chance to review the code, and i have to say, it's a little more complicated than outlined.

Key element is, that you need a service (which I wrote in C++) which runs with system permissions.
This service has to copy the impersonation token from the `winlogon` process and after that, launch a new process with that new token.

Here is some API functions for reference:

- `GetTokenInformation`
- `OpenProcessToken`
- `DuplicateTokenEx`
- `AdjustTokenPrivileges`